# Is it possible to kill two masters out of three in DC/OS - Mesos?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I am currently configuring and adapting some apps to run on the DC/OS. We chose to install the HA-ThreeMaster AWS template.

Recently I was asked to downscale the cluster during development. While removing slave nodes is trivial, I couldn't find any information on how to bring down Master nodes.

I know that they should always have an odd number so I was thinking to remove the two non-leader ec2 instances. Can this be done without destroying the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your setup. 
First check your quorum size:
cat /etc/mesos-master/quorum

Than check this
http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/operational-guide/

> Decreasing the quorum size

```
The following steps indicate how to decrement the quorum size, using 5 -> 3 masters as an example (quorum size 3 -> 2):

Initially, 5 masters are running with --quorum=3
Remove 2 masters from the cluster, ensure they will not be restarted (see NOTE section above). Now 3 masters are running with --quorum=3
Restart the 3 masters with --quorum=2
To decrease the quorum by N, repeat this process to decrement the quorum size N times.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work. A master count of three will allow one master to fail, and the remaining two can still find a quorum. If you only have one remaining master, the quorum can't be reached.